# How can I trust Google Drive web uploads in general?

Tags: google-drive, upload

You see, when I use Dropbox - the client, it will resume uploads/downloads if the connection goes dead. It will also make sure the upload/download is 100% complete, secure, done. If the file is marked by that green icon, I can be a hundred percent sure that it's there.

**How can I be sure about the same with web uploads?**
If you copy to an  rsync or sftp host, it let's me check the exact sizes, and re-copy the file if they differ. But what about the files I upload via my Chrome browser (let's say).

**So... a complete usecase...**

1. Let's say I want to upload a backup. It is not that big, let's say, only 5gb in size.
2. It takes time, even with most FTTH connections to get it up.
3. Then it's there, it appears on Google Drive for example.
4. But **how do I know if it arrived safely**?
5. Do they check this on server side? (Is that even possible?)

   - But it's not just that one file. Like I want to upload a whole folder of source code, or important rar files. I know installing Drive client is an option, but if you have an SSD let's say, and you bought a Terabyte-sized subscription, then that's just not possible.

Comment: Please, feel free to edit my question, especially regarding the terminology. Not an expert of web apps.

Comment: Size is a reliable indicator of corruption only when it differs, not when it matches. You may want to explore the developer API for MD5 or such hash retrieval, although I don't know if the API offers this feature. And what's not possible? You wouldn't be the first to upload a TB. Source code should first be backed up to a remote `git` or `hg` repo.